# .ssh/config ProxyCommand with a variable port

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, openssh, ssh-config

In the environment I work in, we use tunnels to SSH to various servers.  For example, I'll 'ssh -p XXXXX username@localhost' to reach the server.

If the port was always the same, I could do this, and I'd be done:

```
Host somehost
  User bryan
  Hostname localhost
  Port 12345
  ProxyCommand ssh -p 2218 bryan@first.server.com -W %h:%p
```

However, the port used can and will change if the tunnel goes down and comes back up. This isn't something I have the ability to change - it's built into the infrastructure.  So, I wrote a program to find the current port.  But I don't know how to either:

a) Run that program and use the output for the %p variable; or
b) Run a cron job on first.server.com to write out a text file with the port in it, or set an environment variable, or something.

In effect, I want to do this.  Is it possible?

```
Host somehost
  User bryan
  Hostname localhost
  Port `sh get_port_for_somehost.sh`
  ProxyCommand ssh -p 2218 bryan@first.server.com -W %h:%p
```

The only thing I can think of right now is to run a program on my laptop which rewrites my .ssh/config after going and querying what the ports currently are, but I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: There may be something I don't understand about your setup. Why are you specifying a `Port` directive and then using `%p` in the `ProxyCommand`, if specifying `Port` is a problem? Why not use `ssh -W %h:$(get_port_for %h) …` as the `ProxyCommand`?

Comment: @Gilles, I'm just starting to use .ssh/config, so I think that's just a case of my misunderstanding what the best use case is.  I will try out what you suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to write a script in the configuration file to pull a variable for port number.

But you can write a `bash` function to get the port for you and place it into the correct place. For example place the following to the `~/.bashrc`:

```
function ssh-dynamic() {
  PORT=`sh get_port_for_somehost.sh`
  exec ssh -p "$PORT" somehost "$@"
}
```

where the other configuration may stay in the `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Just to verify, this needs to be on the initiating system (i.e., my laptop), correct?  Or could I do this on the proxy server via ProxyCommand or another method?

Comment: This needs to be on the initiating system. The other hosts using `ProxyCommand` are used merely for dumb io redirection. I didn't test the function, but you should be able to get the idea from it.

Comment: While this appears to be the only option as long as using the `-p` option is required, there is absolutely no point in using that option, because it will only be interpreted by the ProxyCommand—which can be trivially modified to get it directly.